# REST API - doesn't show anything

Tags: android, rest

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7r_vdwmW0o) tutorial about Rest API in android. I did everything what was in this video and I'm not getting any data, aslo I've changed the link as shown in but I'm not getting any data. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView value;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new JSONTask().execute("https://jsonparsingdemo-cec5b.firebaseapp.com/jsonData/moviesDemoItem.txt");
            }
        });    
    }

    public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line ="";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                // to bedzie wyswietlone

                String finalJson = buffer.toString();
                JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
                JSONArray parrentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("movies");

                JSONObject finalObject = parrentArray.getJSONObject(0);
                String movieName = finalObject.getString("movie");
                int movieYear = finalObject.getInt("year");

                return movieName;

            }catch (MalformedURLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if(connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if(reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            value.setText(result);
        }
    }

}
```

I'm beginner in android, please don't say that I should start with something easier. I'm doing it for my Django project, I want to create mobile app for it. Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: I tried to debug your app and it seems that as long as the line `connection.connect();` gets executed it then falls to the `finally` statement and eventually returns `null`. Don't know why it behaves like this.

Comment: Hi, despite discouraging us to recommend something "easier", Retrofit is a way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Hiiii, i have checked your code and there is a issue because "https" connection.
You can use Volley library for that. Use below code for get response from yout api link.

Firstly add compile ‘com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0’ in yout build.gradle file.

now add below code in your activity

```
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new 
    JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://jsonparsingdemo-
    cec5b.firebaseapp.com/jsonData/moviesDemoItem.txt", null, new 
    Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+response, 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = 
    Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```